# Creating Oracle Trigger to copy/INSERT single record on UPDATE into new table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, toad

I am attempting to setup a Trigger in my Oracle Database that fires every time a record is UPDATE'd in `Table1`. When the trigger executes (after?), I want to copy/insert the `:old` record values for all fields in the record which was updated into a `HistoryTable`. The only difference between the 2 tables is the inclusion of a `[Table1_ID]` field to reference all history records for that particular `Table1.[ID]`:

```
[Table1] - [ID][col1][col2][col3][etc.]
[HistoryTable] - [ID][Table1_ID][col1][col2][col3][etc.]
```

Does anyone know how to set this up? I've attempt to script it as shown below with no luck thus far, and haven't figured out how to specify the action exactly within the `TOAD` gui. I've already got a `Sequence/Trigger` pair in place so that the `[ID]` field for `HistoryTable` is auto-incremented each time a new record is inserted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCHEMA1.ITEM_UPDATED_TRG
AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.HISTORYTABLE (Table1_ID, col1, col2, col3, etc.)
    VALUES (:OLD.ID, :OLD.col1, :OLD.col2, :OLD.col3, :OLD.etc);
END;
ShOW ERRORS;
```

Output window comes up with `Warning: compiled but with compilation errors - No errors.`...?

Comment: What does "no luck" mean?  Are you getting an error?  What error?  Your code looks reasonable enough to me.

Comment: @JustinCave - see my extra information at the end of the post.

Comment: Is that the full text of the Warning returned? Like Justin Cave, I don't see any issues with the sample provided. The `DECLARE` is unnecessary, but shouldn't break it.

Comment: You haven't shown a `/` between the create and the show, but the errors seem like you have one really. Are you connected as `schema1` or another user (hopefully not SYS)? The basic form of `show errors` doesn't work across schemas. You can query `all_errors` or `dba_errors` to see if that shows the actual problem. You're qualifying the trigger and the insert with the schema but not the base table, which *might* be the underlying issue.